# Python/C++ library to find location of characters in image

Tags: c++, python, image-recognition

I'm looking for a Python or C++ library which will find characters in an image and return the location and bounding boxes of those characters. If the library happens to have documentation with examples, this is a plus.

It is not important that the library be able to recognise words.

The characters are non-obfuscated and in a simplistic font, such as Arial.

Comment: Is it images? If not, then you can simply render the Arial characters and find it in the image (hint: PIL is an image-processing library).

Comment: There's [python-tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/) which is a Python wrapper around Google's [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) OCR library. However, I'm not sure if it provides access to bounding boxes and similar.

Comment: @user176581, I'm afraid it is images. There are some simple background colors which should not overly complicate the task of finding letters, but do frustrate simple approaches.

Comment: @Richard then perhaps you can use the same method I had described except allowing for slight differences.

Comment: @Richard Can you post some representative images that you will be dealing with? By simple background colors do you mean simply a single solid colors but could be affected by noise (i.e. even though the eye perceive them to be the same color they are not exactly the same due to noise), patterns, or smth akin to CAPTCHA? Also, are your characters all have the same font size and font etc? Or are they mixed?

Comment: @lightalchemist, I'll try to put some pictures together. All characters have the same font size and font. Background colour around each character will have only minor variations in shade - nothing approach a captcha.

Comment: @Richard Yep it is best that you do. Actually depending on how "simple" your background is, the problem can be easy or fairly difficult. By easy, I mean for cases where you have text on a solid colored background say blue color, you can try to threshold the background, run a connected component algorithm such as OpenCV's findContours(...) then for each contour, get the bounding box. This happens rarely when dealing with real world images such as family photo albums or advertisments (which must have logos censored) etc. but if that is your case then you are in luck.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a standard library to do this. There are various papers and examples for this kind of task though: basically you need to do some preprocessing on the image to find text and then determine the bounding box. See for example [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464397/image-preprocessing-for-text-recognition) for some things.

Libraries such as [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) might be helpful in implementing this.