# Watershed in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I want to perform an oversegmentation of image using watershed method. Reading documentation, I'd need to use findContour and drawContour function to create marker. How can I use that?

This is my current code,

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

im=cv2.imread('balls.jpg')
marker=np.zeros(im.shape[:2])
marker[::30,::30]=200
marker=np.int32(marker)

cv2.watershed(im,marker)
out=cv2.convertScaleAbs(marker)

cv2.namedWindow('Out')
cv2.imshow('Out', out)
cv2.waitKey()
```

P/S: There's another question on this, but they used other approach(based on foreground and background. I want to use contours instead).

This is my goal: produce an oversegmetnation of image:

[image]

Input image can be downloaded from here:
http://decsai.ugr.es/~javier/denoise/peppers256.png

Comment: It will help if you post a sample image.

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294859/how-to-define-the-markers-for-watershed-in-opencv/11438165#11438165

Comment: Thanks for the link, but because I want to produce an oversegmentation, so the marker image can't be foreground and background. I tried to have the marks put evenly (marker[::30,::30]=200) but that does not produce any segmentation result.

Comment: Your example looks like intensity-based segmentation