# Adaptive threshold with blurry image

Tags: opencv, adaptive-threshold

I'm in search for best Adaptive Threshold method for image binarization. But I have any problems with dark and blurry image.
**Input image:**
[image: Let the Image load...]

and when I use Adaptive threshold method I receive this
**Output Image**:
[image: Let the Image load...]

This is not good for me! 
So, could someone help me fix this problem?

---

another image : [image]

and : [image]

the first seem very bad with @Hammer'solution (i must chose c channel) , the second i can use adaptive threshold normal . 
so i want to find the best solution for all cases .

thank Again !

Answer (score 9):

It seems like color is a much better indicator for segmentation in your image than intensity.  Try converting it to HSV and then running OTSU on the H channel.

in python

```
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.cv.CV_BGR2HSV)
cv2.imshow('hsv', hsv[:,:,0])
(thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(hsv[:,:,0], 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imshow('OTSU', im_bw)
```

gives (hsv)

[image]

and then (OTSU)

[image]

A little eroding and dilating and you should be good to go

Comment: yes, Hammer thank for your question . that seem is good for this case and bad for any . so how can i chose the best solution ? thank !

Comment: @minhthuan What's the difference result among this good one and other bad ones? Show some images that don't fit Hammer's solution.

Comment: Nice answer. What about choosing thresholds, to get multiple levels ? There is already some OpenCv magic ?

Answer (score 6):

You might be interested in [these](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#adaptive-thresholding) adaptive thresholds used by openCV.

I used the adaptive mean threshold. You may have to play with the parameters a bit, but if your images are similar (same size etc), hopefully there won't be too much tweaking required.

```python
# Smooth image
filtered = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(input_image.astype(np.uint8), 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 41, 3)

# Some morphology to clean up image
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(filtered, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(opening, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The following code ...

```
im=cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,111,3)
cv2.imshow('mkm',im)`
```

... gives a good result:

[image: adaptive image]

Answer (score 1):

If a single threshold is not enough to separate all images, you could try the [Watershed algorithm](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#watershed) with two thresholds.

Use a high threshold to get an image with segments that are definitely part of a digit, and a high inverse threshold to get an image with segments that are definitely not part of a digit.

Erode both images a bit to increase the certainty.

Then use the 2 images as seeds for Watershed.

[Here is an answer where this is done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11438165/145999)