# Cut a certain part of an image and paste it in other image

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing

I there any library in Python so that you can cut a certain part of an image (like a person) and paste it in other image?

Comment: Transposing a collection of pixels from one image to another is simple with [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/). Figuring out which pixels are "person" pixels, is probably a big unsolved problem in computer vision.

Answer (score 0):

You can use segmentation technique(seed based approach) in first image and then OpenCV library to place it onto another image by creating a mask.

Comment: Actually I was talking about OpenCV : http://opencv.org/ But the linked you shared looks ok too. OpenCV based example: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_watershed/py_watershed.html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294859/how-to-define-the-markers-for-watershed-in-opencv