# How to create polygons for watershed segmentation

Tags: python, opencv, watershed

I have an image and would like to create polygons of segments this image using marker-controlled watershed. I wrote the following code but I can't separate objects attached each other and create the polygons of the object.

How can solve those issues? Thanks so  much for your help.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc
import scipy.ndimage as snd
# image is read and is converted to a numpy array
img = cv2.imread('D:/exam_watershed/Example_2_medicine/Medicine_create_poly/medicine.jpg')
# image is convereted to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# binary thresholding is done using the threshold
# from Otsu's method
ret1,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
# foreground pixels are determined by
# performing erosion
fore_ground = cv2.erode(thresh1,None,iterations = 3)
bgt = cv2.dilate(thresh1,None,iterations = 3)
ret,back_ground = cv2.threshold(bgt,1,100,1)
# marker is determined by adding foreground and background pixels
marker = cv2.add(fore_ground,back_ground)
# converting marker to 32 int
marker32 = np.int32(marker)
cv2.watershed(img,marker32)
res = scipy.misc.toimage(marker32)
res.save('D:/exam_watershed/Example_2_medicine/Medicine_create_poly/res_output.png')
```

[image: original image]

[image: image after segment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294859/how-to-define-the-markers-for-watershed-in-opencv) seems to be pretty close to your needs, since the example uses the exact same image as yours.

To transform the resulting "dams" into polygons, I suggest using [cv2.findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#cv2.findContours) together with [cv2.approxPolyDP](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=approxpoly#cv2.approxPolyDP) on the result image.

Comment: Follow your suggests, I convert the segmentation image into binary image and then run the contours:
_, contours1, _= cv2.findContours(thresh3,cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE). Then running functions:
    def approxing(cnts):
    back = []
    closed = True
    for cnt in cnts:
        epsilon = 10
        cnt2 = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, epsilon, closed)
        back.append(cnt2)
    return back
c = approxing(contours1).    And save the result, image_out=cv2.imwrite('D:/contour2.jpg',c). However it has error image is not a numpy or scalar. How to fix this? THanks